# How can I populate a list array list

Tags: c#

How should I add new data to the list with { dt, accumulated, state } from my example code.

Finally print in JSON format.

My code snippet:

```
public class ObjectsClass
{
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }    
    public double accumulated { get; set; } 
    public int state { get; set; }
}
public class ArrayObjectClass
{
    public List<ObjectsClass> intervalo { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var lista = new ArrayObjectClass();
    lista.Add( ..//TODO ... );
       
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);
    var JSONPretty = JValue.Parse(json).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);  
    JSONPretty.Dump();
}
```

Comment: You would add instances of `ArrayObjectClass`. Then inside that instance, you would add instances of `ObjectsClass` to `intervalo`. What's the issue here?

Comment: I don't know how to fill in data

Comment: There's examples in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0). Look specifically at the section "// Add parts to the list.".

Comment: I already tried that and it works, but my example has List<ObjectsClass> intervalo and I don't know how to do it there.

Comment: Simple approach: Create a new `ArrayObjectClass` instance, assign it to a variable. Assign a new list to `intervalo` in that instance, and add items to it the same way you're adding them to `ArrObj`. Then add the `ArrayObjectClass` instance to the `ArrObj` list. Or look at [collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers).

Comment: There are some really great articles on the Microsoft Docs site on building and constructing collection classes

Comment: You should leave your question as it was, and then post an answer to your own question. :) I'm glad you got it sorted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the code is complete and working:

```
public class ObjectsClass
{
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }    
    public double accumulated { get; set; } 
    public int state { get; set; }
}
public class ArrayObjectClass
{
    public IList<ObjectsClass> intervalo { get; } = new List<ObjectsClass>();
}

void Main()
{
   ArrayObjectClass lista = new ArrayObjectClass
   {
       intervalo =
       {
           new ObjectsClass{ dt = new DateTime(2022, 09, 05, 00, 00, 00), accumulated = 0, state = 0 },
           new ObjectsClass{ dt = new DateTime(2022, 09, 05, 00, 00, 01), accumulated = 0, state = 0 },
           new ObjectsClass{ dt = new DateTime(2022, 09, 05, 00, 00, 02), accumulated = 0, state = 0 }
       }
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);
       var JSONPretty = JValue.Parse(json).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);   
       JSONPretty.Dump();
    }
}
```

JSON response:

```
{
      "intervalo": [
        {
          "dt": "2022-09-05T00:00:00",      
          "accumulated": 0.0,  
          "state": 0
        },
        {
          "dt": "2022-09-05T00:00:01",     
          "accumulated": 0.0,  
          "state": 0
        },
        {
          "dt": "2022-09-05T00:00:02",    
          "accumulated": 0.0,   
          "state": 0
        }
      ]
 }
```